# For Loop with Bool

Tags: python, for-loop, boolean, divide-by-zero

I have a simple loop which gets stuck on a division by zero error.  I am running a bool to filter out zero-value denominators, but for some reason the bool I used isn't working.  Can someone please help?  I am using python 2.6.5

Here is a sample from my code:

```
for i in range(0,len(lines)):
    line = lines[i]
    line = line.split(";")
    leansz = line[9]
    FW = line[34]
    FS = line[35]  
    print "FS: %s  %s"%(FS,type(FS))  #troubleshooting the denominator and its type
    if FS == "0":  #I have tried FS == 0 and FS == "0" to no avail
        print 'FS == "0"' #checking if bool is working
        continue  #return to top of loop if denominator is zero
    LnSzRa = float(leansz)/(float(FS)/2)  #division by zero error
```

Here is a sample of what is returned and then the error:

```
FS: 184
  <type 'str'>
FS: 1241
  <type 'str'>
FS: 2763
  <type 'str'>
FS: 1073
  <type 'str'>
FS: 971
  <type 'str'>
FS: 0
  <type 'str'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mpreader.py", line 50, in <module>
    LnSzRa = float(leansz)/(float(FS)/2)
ZeroDivisionError: float division
```

Comment: Any reason why you are not using the `csv` module to handle your lines?

Comment: I have always been able to read csv files with this command without apparent issues, except on my macbook (today ironically).  I just need to get more familiar with the csv module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `FS` value is a **string** that includes the newline character from the file still, so test for a string value:

```
if FS == '0\n':
```

or strip the newline:

if FS.strip() == '0':

or turn `FS` into a float first:

```
if float(FS) == 0:
```

or strip `line` while splitting:

```
line = line.strip().split(';')
```

Further tips:

- Just loop over `lines` directly; don't use `range()`:

  ```
  for line in lines:
      line = line.strip()
      # do something with `line`
  ```

  Even if you still need an index *as well*, you use `enumerate()` to generate the index:

  ```
  for i, line in enumerate(lines):
      line = line.strip()
      # do something with `line` and `i`.
  ```
- You can use the `csv` module to handle splitting data files into rows:

  ```
  import csv

  with open(somefile, 'rb') as inputfile:
      reader = csv.reader(inputfile, delimiter=';')
      for row in reader:
          leansz, FW, FS = map(float, (row[9], row[34], row[35]))
          if not FS: continue
          LnSzRa = leansz / (FS / 2)
  ```

Comment: Actually, I just edited this.  I have tried FS == "0" originally.  It returned the same error.  I just tried with FS == "0" again, but no success.

Comment: @user2136314: ah, you also have the newline still in the value.

Comment: part of the issue with not using the CSV module is my lack of knowledge of the "with open as file" syntax, which is used in all the documentation I could find about the CSV module. I learned python 2.4 originally and now I am now using python 2.6.5.  Does 2.6.5 support that syntax?

Comment: @user2136314: Context managers were added in Python 2.5 (with a `from __future__ import with_statement` syntax), and are fully supported in Python 2.6.

Comment: @user2136314: The CSV module doesn't require using files as context managers however, a simple `open()` then explicit `.close()` later on would suffice.

Comment: I used the strip line method and it worked.  Thank you for all your tips.  The additional comments beyond original intent of my question were very helpful and appreciated!